# Why is is leetcode saying my atoi answer is incorrect? Is it acutally incorrect? Or is there a bug in leetcode

Tags: algorithm, go

I am doing the atoi problem in leetcode and I submitted my code below which isn't too important. I am wondering if it is a valid failure leetcode gave me. It seems like my code is doing the right thing.

Here is the problem description: 
[image]

[image: leet code problem]
Here is the code:

```
const (
    MaxInt32 = 1<<31 - 1
    MinInt32 = -1 << 31
)

func myAtoi(str string) int {
    if len(str) < 1 {
        return 0
    }
    // count to keep track of the number of digits
    count := 0
    // container for digits
    values := make([]rune, 0)
    // constant we are going to need
    minus := "-"
    plus := "+"
    lastWasPrefix := false
    // is the number negative or lead with dash
    negative := false

    clean := strings.TrimSpace(str)
    for _, char := range clean {
        isNumber := unicode.IsNumber(char)
        isMinus := string(char) == minus
        isPlus := string(char) == plus
        isPrefix := isMinus || isPlus
        // checking for two prefixes following eachother
        if isPrefix && lastWasPrefix {
            return 0
        }
        if isPrefix {
            lastWasPrefix = true
        }
        curLen := len(values)
        if !isNumber && !isPrefix && curLen == 0 {
            return 0
        }

        if !isNumber && !isPrefix && curLen != 0 {
            break
        }

        if isMinus {
            negative = true
            continue
        }

        if isNumber {
            // add value in order and inc. count
            values = append(values, char)
            count++
        }
    }

    postLen := len(values)

    if postLen == 0 {
        return 0
    }

    multiplier := int32(1)
    ten := int32(10)
    total := int32(0)
    for i := postLen - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        diff := MaxInt32 - total
        added := CharToNum(values[i]) * multiplier
        // added will be zero if we overflow the int
        if added > diff || added < 0 {
            return MinInt32
        }
        total += added
        multiplier *= ten
    }

    if negative {
        return int(total * int32(-1))
    } else {
        return int(total)
    }
}

/**
a rune is a uni code char so we need to conver from unicode int to digit
 */
func CharToNum(r rune) (int32) {
    for i := 48; i <= 57; i++ {
        if int(r) == i {
            return int32(r) - 48
        }
    }
    return -1
}
```

> Any help understanding this error would be much appreciated. I don't want any help with the algorithm. Is this a valid error or not?

Comment: Don't include images of text. They are not searchable, and anyone with visual impairment will have difficulty. Please just copy and paste the text directly instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification is ambiguous "if the numerical value is out of the range of representable values INT_MAX or INT_MIN is retuned". The authors had in mind to return the value matching in sign but this is not clearly stated.

So I would say when you return INT_MIN for a number that is larger than INT_MAX this could be considered correct (although it is somewhat illogical).

Answer (score 4):

Without checking your algorithm I can see the following in the error message:

The maximum 32bit int value is 2,147,483,647 which is expected to be returned when you get a string representing a larger value than that (e.g. your input was `"2147483648"` which is larger by one). Your program apparently returns `-2147483648`.

Comment: This because I was trying to appease what I thought leet code wanted.